# How to hide scroll inside div of a Component in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

In a React project I've details of wallet scrolling in a div named 'History'. Issue is that history details is scrolling without any issue, but, I want to hide inside 'History' div. How could it be done? Any appropriate solution?

Below is the code reference

```
const navScrollStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: "120px",
    display: "table",
    overflowY: "auto",
    maxWidth: "auto",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
}));

const navBodyStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    top: "0px",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    textAlign: "center",
    background: "white",
    zIndex: "9",
    height: "100%",
    overflowY: "auto"
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    color: "purple"
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "black"
  }
}));

const gridClassStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    zIndex: "100",
    flexGrow: 1,
    position: "fixed",
    top: "0px",
    background: "white",
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    boxShadow: "5px 10px 18px #888888"
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    color: "purple"
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "black"
  }
}));

const useStyles5 = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    },
    textAlign: "center",
    width: "100%"
  }
}));

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    top: "20px",
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: "auto"
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4)
  }
}));

const TestPageScroll = () => {
  const navBody = navBodyStyle();
  const navScroll = navScrollStyle();
  const gridClass = gridClassStyle();

  const classes5 = useStyles5();

  const classes = useStyles();

  const NavPart = () => (
    <Grid className={gridClass.root} container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={4} style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        <IconButton
          edge="start"
          className={gridClass.menuButton}
          color="inherit"
          aria-label="menu"
        >
          <Link to="/">
            <ArrowBackIcon />
          </Link>
        </IconButton>
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        item
        xs={4}
        style={{ textAlign: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h6" className={gridClass.title}>
          <h2>Test Scroll</h2>
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4} style={{ textAlign: "right", marginTop: "2%" }}>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="account of current user"
          aria-controls="menu-appbar"
          aria-haspopup="true"
        >
          <AccountCircle style={{ fontSize: "30px" }} />
        </IconButton>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
  return (
    <div className={navBody.root}>
      {NavPart()}
      <div className={navScroll.root}>

      </div>

      {/* Here the main code begins */}
      <div style={{ height: "100px" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            position: "fixed",
            zIndex: "100",
            background: "white",
            width: "100%"
          }}
        >
          <h2>History</h2>
        </div>
        <hr />

        <List
          component="nav"
          aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
          className={classes.root}
        >
          <>
            {/* Here purposely List are added to test overflow */}
            <div style={{ overflowY: "auto", background: "red" }}>
              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History1</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />

              <ListItem>
                <h6>Wallet History</h6>
              </ListItem>
              <Divider />
            </div>
          </>
        </List>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see below in the picture, Wallet history details is seen clearly which I want to hide inside 'History' div

[image]

Here is the codesandbox link for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-forked-71op5
Please click on 'WALLET' button when page loads

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `History` `div` is `fixed` and your `Wallet History List div` has no bounds on `height` which is getting scrolled behind the `fixed div`s above. one way to solve this problem is to limit your `height` of your  `Wallet History List div` and make it `fixed` as well.

eg. add these style to your `div` for list

`maxHeight : "800px", position :"fixed", width:"100%"`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-forked-71op5?file=/src/components/TestPageScroll.js:4244-4295

Comment: Its not working man... If you don't mind, can you directly update my codesandbox?

Comment: i added this  `style={{
 overflowY: "auto",
 background: "red",
 maxHeight: "600px",
 position: "fixed",
 width: "100%"
   }}`
link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-forked-3rkoy?file=/src/components/TestPageScroll.js:4209-4407

Comment: Yes now its fine... Thanks